# WSO2 IS 5.10 create index on table IDN_RECOVERY_DATA

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have the following query that is doing a `seq_scan` in the `IDN_RECOVERY_DATA` table
I would like to create an index to avoid that `seq_scan`, do you think there is a problem?

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
IDN_RECOVERY_DATA
WHERE LOWER (USER_NAME)=LOWER ($1) AND USER_DOMAIN =$2 AND TENANT_ID =$3
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Dangal can you explain why do you need this query. Although you used a index since you use the Lower() this query will miss the index

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an MSSQL or MySQL database, you can avoid this LOWER() function on SQL queries with the following user store property. Because those DB engines are doing case insensitive comparisons by default.

```
<Property name="CaseInsensitiveUsername">false</Property>
```

If you are using a different database, you can create an index with LOWER() function like below.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_IRD_LUDT ON IDN_RECOVERY_DATA (LOWER(USER_NAME), USER_DOMAIN, TENANT_ID);
```